# Search by numeric Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Using Sql Server 2005

Table1

```
ID Value

ABC001
BCE002
...
```

I have search column, when i search the id like this "001" it is showing empty, when I search "ABC001" then it is showing the values.

Query

```
Select * from table where id = '" & txtid & "'
```

txtid = textbox

I want to search only the numeric value in the ID.

How to write a query for the numeric search.

Need Query Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from MyTable
where Value LIKE '[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]001'
```

OR

```
select * from MyTable
where Value LIKE '[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]' + RIGHT('000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @id), 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE id LIKE '%001'
```

Comment: This is **guaranteed** to suppress any index use and thus will always result in a table scan - not very efficient...

Comment: @Marc and there's a solution that does not scan?

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by Mitch Wheat will work if every ID you give is 3 letters in caps followed by a numberical value which has 3 digits.

The answer given by rayman86 essentially disregards anything in the front. It merely looks for anything that ends with 001.

If the length of the ID varies and/or the first few characters are not even letters, it's better to use the code that rayman86 has provided. So just use the `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID LIKE '%Numbers'` where Numbers is your numerical value.

Comment: Mitch Wheat's answer will at least use an index most likely. Anything with a leading % won't.

Comment: @gbn it won't. All assumptions, but I will assume that the data is equally distributed along `lead char in (A-Z)` in which case the selectivity of the range `like '[a-z]..'` = 1 and completely useless for index usage.

Comment: Using % is not exactly recommended. But if the first 3 digits are always `[A-Z]`, then it'd be fine. The answer given by Richard pretty much strips much of the data out. But if only the number matters, then it's fine. Just remember that you may have IDs with the same numerical value in the real world. So technically, all of these methods won't work in the working world. But for now, it should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

A literal interpretation of the question without making any assumptions:

Create this function

```
create function dbo.numericonly(@s varchar(max))
returns float as
begin
declare @i int set @i = 1
while @i <= len(@s)
  if ascii(substring(@s,@i,1)) between 48 and 57
    set @i = @i + 1
  else
    set @s = stuff(@s,@i,1,'')
return @s
end
GO
```

Use this query

```
Select * from table1 where dbo.numericonly(id) = '" & txtid & "'
```